# How can we change the datatype for jsonb column?

Tags: python, postgresql, jsonb, dbt

I have a code where I'm flattening the jsonb column and I have created a macro for it. First, it takes three arguments model_name is the database from where I'm pulling the data,

and json_column is the column that has JSON info. Now when I transform this data and flat the result the datatype for all the fields is text. I think its because of this ->>
the operator which converts all values to string. I just want to change the type of the field to what it is. If it is a string then it's a string.

after flattening the jsonb this is what I get

[image]

```
{% macro flatten_json(model_name, json_column) %}
  
{% set survey_methods_query %}

SELECT DISTINCT(jsonb_object_keys({{json_column}})) as column_name
from {{model_name}}
{% endset %}

{% set results = run_query(survey_methods_query) %}

{% if execute %}
{# Return the first column #}
{% set results_list = results.columns[0].values() %}
{% else %}
{% set results_list = [] %}
{% endif %}

select
_airbyte_ab_id,
_airbyte_data,
{% for column_name in results_list %}
_airbyte_data ->>'{{ column_name }}' as {{ column_name }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
from {{model_name}}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: just replace `->>`by `->`

Comment: No. It doesn't work. Every field will become the jsonb type

Comment: "I just want to change the type of the field to what it is" : it is a jsonb type indeed... So what do you really want : transform the jsonb type into the "corresponding" sql type, knowing that there is no exact correspondance between the jsonb types and the sql types (see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-TYPE-MAPPING-TABLE))

Comment: I have mentioned that I have flatten the jsonb data. The data after which we get after flattening is coming as text. I want to do type check for that fields. Right now every field is coming as string. I'll update the info

Comment: I have added the image after flattening the jsonb column. You can see every field coming as text.

Comment: You can try to CAST the data according to the jsonb type; something like `CASE WHEN jsonb_typeof(_airbyte_data ->'{{ column_name }}') = 'number' THEN CAST(_airbyte_data ->>'{{ column_name }}' AS numeric) WHEN jsonb_typeof(_airbyte_data ->'{{ column_name }}') = 'boolean' THEN CAST(_airbyte_data ->>'{{ column_name }}' AS boolean) ELSE _airbyte_data ->>'{{ column_name }}' END`